# Orientation issue with UITabBarController iOS

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, orientation

i created xib with UITabBarController in that i have 3 navigationControllers for 3 view controllers.

my problem is when i rotate **shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation** is not calling.

can any one help me how to use **shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation** in UITabBarContoller views.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I'm also facing this issue. I have two Tab Bar Controllers on the same page. Worked fine with a single Tab Bar Controller. Only one is graphically linked to the rootviewcontroller. There is no code to paste as this is setup graphically.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of a UITabBarController, if you want the view to rotate you have return YES from the method `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` in all of your view controllers, otherwise it won't rotate.

Comment: Yes i wrote the below code in all three viewcontrollers but shouldAutoRotate method is not getting called when i rotate:   "- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 // Return YES for supported orientations.
 if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
 {
  return YES;
 }
 else
  return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}"

Comment: try this. (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOr‌​ientation {
 return YES;
}

Comment: u r returning YES for iPad else you are not returning... tell me you are making app for iPhone or iPad or Both.?

Comment: i am making the app for both and i tried by returning Yes Only but still same problem

Comment: Dude if your writing return YES in all your view controllers in that method then it should work surely as i had also faced that problem and then solved it by doing what i am saying right now.Otherwise do one thing post your code by editing your question. I am sure many other people will also be happy to help you.

Comment: I'm also facing this issue.  I have two Tab Bar Controllers on the same page.  Worked fine with a single Tab Bar Controller.  Only one is graphically linked to the rootviewcontroller. There is no code to paste as this is setup graphically.  Please don't get defensive, mAc. Your answer has helped quite a few people.  Same result, but a different cause.